# Create Radio Button Xamarin forms in C# ONLY

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to create a Radio Button programmatically in C# in Xamarin forms in my shared project?
Example you can create checkboxes like so: CheckBox Mybox = new CheckBox();

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+radio+button.  Please attempt to do a minimal amount of research before posting.  This took me 5s to find

Comment: Yes, I have seen a lot of examples using xaml but have not seen any using C#, hence why I am asking if it is actually possible

Comment: `var radio = new RadioButton();`

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this in my shared project but it does not seem to be working. I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: then you should post the code you are using and explain what problems you are having and ask for help solving it.  That is a much better approach than just asking "is it possible" which is a yes or no question.

Answer (score 2):

I create RadioButton by C# using **Xamarin.forms version 5.0**, you can take a look the following code:

```
 public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RadioButton rbtn1 = new RadioButton();
        rbtn1.Content = "cat";

        RadioButton rbtn2 = new RadioButton();
        rbtn2.Content = "dog";

        layout1.Children.Add(rbtn1);
        layout1.Children.Add(rbtn2);
    }
```

Adding RedioButton in Stacklayout.

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout x:Name="layout1">
        <Label
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Note: I test RadioButton in Xamarin.Forms 4.8 version, there are some problems, so suggest you use Xamarin.forms version 5.0 to test.